# How do you get the max date from duplicate queries and remove duplicate

Tags: mysql

How do you get the records that contain the max value for each grouped set?

### Product | Date out

```
Book 1| 01-01-2019
Book 2| 05-03-2021
Book 3| 06-05-2021
Book 1| 01-02-2019
Book 1| 30-11-2021
Book 1| 01-12-2022
```

I tried select book_id, max(book_dateout) from products;

Desired result set:

```
Book 1| 01-12-2022
Book 2| 05-03-2021
Book 3| 06-05-2021
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL usually represents dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd. In that case you could just use

```
select book_id, max(book_dateout) 
from products 
group by book_id;
```

If you have them stored as strings, you can use

```
select book_id, date_format(max(str_to_date(book_dateout, '%d-%m-%Y')), '%d-%m-%Y')
from products 
group by book_id;
```